# Euler's Demonstration

Tags: taylor-expansion, math-history

Just wondering if anyone could help (give steps or explanation) on how to give Euler's Demonstration. A question I've come across is:

> Give Euler's Demonstration that
>   $$ \sum^{\infty}_{k=1} \frac {1} {(2k-1)^2}=\frac {\pi^2}{8} $$

I think I need the expansion of cos but I'm unsure how to go about showing the above. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's the same approach as he did for the [Basel problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem), but with cosine instead of sine. (Try to take the logic for how he guessed the infinite product expansion of sine and transfer it to cosine.)

Comment: The Aigner and Ziegler book re-expresses the sum as the double integral $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1-x^2 y^2} dx dy$ then uses a substitution to evaluate the integral. The substitution made uses new variables $u$ and $v$ where $x = \sin u / \cos v$ and $y = \sin v / \cos u$.

Comment: This is derived from the Fourier transform of the square wave. It's rather too involved to write up here as an answer. However, all the gory details can be found in Paul J. Nahin's *Dr. Euler's Fabulous Formula: Cures Many Mathematical Ills*, Princeton,  2006. It is frequently reported in the form $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

Answer (score 1):

This gives the approach in Aigner and Ziegler described earlier.
First, define an integral $I$ and show it is equal to the sum over $k$ of $1/(2k+1)^2$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
I =
\int_0^1
\int_0^1
\frac{1}{1 - x^2 y^2}
dx dy
&=
\int_0^1
\int_0^1
\sum_{k=0}^\infty
(x^2 y^2)^k
dx dy
\\
&=
\int_0^1
\left(
\sum_{k=0}^\infty
\int_0^1
x^{2k} y^{2k}
dx
\right)
dy
\\
&=
\int_0^1
\left(
\sum_{k=0}^\infty
\frac{1}{2k+1}
y^{2k}
\right)
dy
\\
&=
\sum_{k=0}^\infty
\left(
\int_0^1
\frac{1}{2k+1}
y^{2k}
dy
\right)
\\
&=
\sum_{k=0}^\infty
\frac{1}{(2k+1)^2}
\end{aligned}
$$

So we want to find 
$$
I = \iint\limits_{S}  f(x,y) dx dy 
$$
where 
$S$ is the unit square $0 < x,y < 1$
and
$f = \frac{1}{1 - x^2 y^2}$

Define a substitution $(x,y)$ to $(u,v)$ with the transformation:
$$
x = \frac{\sin u}{\cos v} \qquad
y = \frac{\sin v}{\cos u}
$$

Under the change of variable we have
$$
I = \iint\limits_{S}  f(x,y) dx dy = \iint\limits_{T} f(x(u,v), y(u,v)) |J| du dv
$$
where $J$ is the determinant of Jacobian under the coordinate transformation.  $T$ is the image of $S$ in the $uv$ plane under the  transformation, which  can be shown to be a bijection between $S$ and $T = \{(u,v) : u, v > 0 \, , \, u + v < \pi / 2\}$ (see below).

The Jacobian determinant is
$$
J = \det
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} \\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial v} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial v} \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Calculate $J$:
$$
J = \det
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{ \cos u }{ \cos v } && \frac{ \sin u \sin v }{ \cos^2 v } \\
\frac{ \sin u \sin v }{ \cos^2 u } && \frac{ \cos v }{ \cos u } \\
\end{pmatrix}
=
1 -
\frac{\sin^2 u \sin^2 v }{\cos^2 u \cos^2 v}
$$

So $|J| = 1 - x^2 y^2$ for $0 < x,y < 1$.

This gives $f |J| = 1$ so the integral becomes
$$
I = \iint\limits_{T} 1 \; du dv = \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{\pi/2 - v} du dv 
= area(T) = \frac{\pi^2}{8}
$$

So, as required, we have shown that
$$
I = 
\sum_{k=0}^\infty
\frac{1}{(2k+1)^2}
=
\frac{\pi^2}{8}
$$

---

The bijection between $S$ and $T$:
The coordinate transformation is described above as a mapping from $T$ to $S$
It is possible to obtain the inverse over $S$

$$
\cos u =
\sqrt{\frac{1-x^2}{1 - x^2 y^2}}
\qquad
\cos v =
\sqrt{
\frac{1-y^2}{1-x^2 y^2}
}
$$

In both directions, it is possible to show that the mappings are 1-1 and that each covers its target region. It is also possible to show that
$$
\sin(u + v)
= 
\frac{x+y}{1+xy}
$$
which helps to determine how the 'top' and 'right' edges of the unit square are together mapped to the segment of the line $u+v = \pi / 2$ between $(0,\pi/2)$ and $(\pi/2,0)$ in the $uv$ plane.